# Cookie Free Subdomain on Flask

Tags: subdomain, cookie

How do you set up a cookie free subdomain on Flask. My website already has subdomains, so setting that up is not a problem. But I'm not sure how to (a) request files across all subdomains (and the main domain) from one specific subdomain and (b) make sure that the designated subdomain does not send cookies with static files.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you would have to make sure whenever you set cookie on any of the other domains and subdomains you do that using fully qualified domain name, check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain

Comment: If that sounds like too much work and monitoring you should look for a CDN

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone reads this: I am going to submit an answer to my own question based on a comment above.

I found that the easiest way, by far, is using a CDN. I used [keycdn](https://keycdn.com). It automatically removes unnecessary cookies and reduces the amount of data when fetching static files.